# Future potential of switching from MySQL to Cassandra (NoSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, nosql, cassandra

I am planning on eventually switching my website's database system from MySQL to NoSQL (in this case Cassandra).

From what I have understood so far about Cassandra, is that there is no such thing as a join, but rather just larger records that work more efficiently.  I am by no standard an expert in NoSQL atm, i actually understand very very little about it and am very confused on how a lot of it works...

One of my goals for my web project is to switch to Python and Cassandra for a more advanced and speedier solution as my website is beginning to grow and I want to be able to scale it easily with additional servers.

Right now i am in the process of designing a new feature for my website, the ability to take files and create folders out of them.  So far this is what I was originally using: [How to join/subquery a second table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869393/how-to-join-subquery-a-second-table/11869474) (A question I just asked)

Then the people were suggesting to normalize the data and make it a 3 table system including one for folders, one for folders/files, and one for files.  @egrunin answered my question and even gave me the info for the NoSQL, but i really wanted to check it with a second source just to make sure that this is the right approach.

Also are there any conversion tools for SQL to NoSQL?

So my ultimate goal is to design this folder/file system in the database (along with other features that I am adding) so that when I switch from SQL to NoSQL I will be ready and the conversion of all of my data will be a lot easier.

Any tutorials, guides, and information on converting SQL to NoSQL, Cassandra, or how NoSQL works is much appreciated, so far the Cassandra documentation has left me very confused.

Comment: Have you done any prototyping / playing around with NoSQL? The biggest difference IMHO is the schemaless nature, so you can evolve your schema over time. I'd suggest trying a few experiments before you try moving your big app, so you get a feel for how data model evolution works in NoSQL.

Comment: I haven't yet experimented with it, but I was hoping someone could give me some guidance on how to try and setup my folder/file database schemas so when i do switch to cassandra it will involve the least amount of conversion as possible :)  If not i will just normalize it for now.  I began to read your information about NoSQL, i will get to more of it later, good stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At Couchbase we've recently done a webinar series about the transition from RDBMS to NoSQL. It's obviously through the lens of JSON documents, but a lot of the lessons will apply to any distributed database.

http://www.couchbase.com/webinars

Answer (score 3):

MasterGberry:

> One of my goals for my web project is to switch to Python and Cassandra for a more advanced and speedier solution as my website is beginning to grow and I want to be able to scale it easily with additional servers.

This is something that you need to clearly quantify before switching to Cassandra.

MySQL can do [amazing things](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101718.do) and so can Cassandra, but switch to Cassandra usually cannot be driven just by wanting to do things faster, because they might not be faster - at least not in the areas where you are used for MySQL to do great (column level numerical aggregates on well defined, tabular data).

I am by no means discouraging the transition, but I am warning about the expectations.

This might be a good reading:
http://itsecrets.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/jumping-from-mysql-to-cassandra-a-success-story/

Comment: One of the advantages of Cassandra is the sociability of database servers, so yes I feel it will in the long run prove to be more efficient for me :)  As far as the blog read, it's actually like 90% copied from the cassandra documentation....still not 10% clear haha.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use a tool like playOrm to support joins BUT on partitions only NOT entire tables.  So if you partition by month or account, you can grab the account 4536 partition and query into that joining it with something else (either another smaller table or another partition from another table).

This is very useful if you have a system with lots of clients and each client is really independent of another client as you can self contain all the client information into that client's partitions of all tables.

later,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra isn't really meant to be the main storage for an application. One of its main purposes is storing sequential data and pulling all that back with a key lookup. One example is logging. Interestingly, the row keys are not sorted, but the column names are. So logging would have a key for every minute and then create a new column for each log entry with a sequential time stamp as the name of the column. That is just one example of course, chat history is another.